# Is there a strictly convex function with a local non-global minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

have tried to prove that if the function is convex, then all locals are also global, but I don't know where I used the fact that the function is convex and not strictly convex.

Suppose $f: X \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} \ $  convex function,that is

$f(\alpha x+ (1-\alpha) y) \leq \alpha f(x)+(1- \alpha )f(y) $

And consider $x_1$ a local minimum of $Y\subset X$ and $x_2$ a global minimum of $f$,that is

$\exists  \ \epsilon>0 $ such that $\forall x \in Y \cap B_{\epsilon}(x_1) , f(x_1)\leq f(x)$

$\forall x\in X$ , $f(x_2)\leq f(x)$

It is always true that

$f(x_2)\leq f(x_1)$

Let's consider the case where $f(x_2)<f(x_1)$, then

$hf(x_2)<hf(x_1)$ $\Rightarrow$  $hf(x_2)+(1-h)f(x_1) < hf(x_1)+(1-h)f(x_1) 
 \ \forall h\in (0,1)$

$f(hx_2 +(1-h)x_1) \leq hf(x_2)+(1-h)f(x_1) <f(x_1)$ ,then

$$ f(hx_2 +(1-h)x_1) <f(x_1) $$

This implies that $ x_1 $ is not a local minimum, as $hx_2 + (1-h) x_1$ is as close to $x_1$ as we want

I don't know where it was used that the function is convex and not strictly convex, it seems to work for strictly convex functions too.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is.  Your proof looks good to me, and since the conclusion is true for any convex function, it must also be true for any strictly convex function.  The difference between the two cases is that  a convex function can have many global minima whereas a global minimum of a *strictly* convex function will always be unique.

Comment: Actually your proof is wrong. To be rigorous, you can not suppose $x_2$ is the global minimum of $f$ since you do not know if such a global minimum does exists.